# Thread sleeping in a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, thread-sleep

I wrote a simple app that adds 100000 lines of "Hello World" to a list using a BackgroundWorker.

Below is the code of the work that my backgroundworker is doing in a separate thread:

```
    private void BgWorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        int min = 0;

        foreach (var hw in hwList)
        {
            //new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            int progress = Convert.ToInt32((Double)min / hwList.Count * 100);
            min++;
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    // Updating the progress
    private void BgWorkerOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs progressChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ProgressBar.Value = progressChangedEventArgs.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

All is working fine, except that if I remove the **Thread.Sleep(1)** the **BackgroundWorker** doesn't report the progress anymore. (I suppose it needs some time). Suspending the thread for 1 ms actually makes the **BackgroundWorker** report the progress but it's very slow.

My question is, is there a way I can get rid of thread sleeping but at the same time making the **BackgroundWorker** report the progress correctly?

From my understanding, suspending the **BackgroundWorker** is inevitable, since the thread needs some time to perform the task, but I'm wondering if there's a workaround.

Comment: What makes you think it's not reporting progress when it goes quickly/without sleeping?

Comment: What is this code doing? It looks like a very simple for loop - reporting progress is probably far more expensive than the rest of the loop.

Comment: "the BackgroundWorker doesn't report the progress anymore" could you elaborate on this statement? I believe it still does report, you are not just consuming it correctly.

Comment: I agree Darek. @xxbbcc, I'd assume this is just to test playing around with BackgroudWorkers, this doesn't have much real functionality to it right now.

Comment: @Darek, well I think it actually does report, but I don't see the progress bar filling up.

Comment: Well then that is a completely different question. Perhaps it just happens too fast to see? Does it end up full? We'd need to see the code to know what's happening there though.

Comment: @bkribbs Yes, I get that. This is a worthless example, though - the most expensive part is the reporting step. There's no point in doing this on a thread.

Comment: @bkribbs it doesn't fill up either. It fills up normally, only if I suspend the thread with Thread.Sleep(1).

Comment: @Darek what if there is a larger amount of data? Let's say 1 billion lines. It takes time, can this progress be reported?

Comment: You might be flooding some internal storage with that many updates.  Try limiting your reporting to every 1% or once a second.

Comment: @deefrson The progress will be reported for 10 data elements, and a billion elements in the exact same way, taking different amounts of time. In the case of 1M, on my machine, it would take 2s, and you 'd likely be able to observe it visually, as long as you are using the correct UI update approach from a background thread. Without seeing your ReportProgress method, it is hard to tell if you will be able to see. Are you using MVVMLight or ReactiveUI by any chance?

Comment: @Darek no, it's pure C# / typical BackgroundWorker code. I updated my code. Well, indeed I'd like to observe it visually, not just every second, but every little amount of time the computer can handle. Unfortunately 1 ms is the lowest value I could set. Maybe I should use a different approach?

Comment: @deefrson Since progress is an int, you won't see any difference between the 1st and 10,000th iteration of a 2,000,000 loop.  Both are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had issues where i was reporting progress to often, furthermore there is no reason to report the same progress so many times waste of cpu cycles.

```
 private void BgWorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int oldProgress = 0;
        foreach (var hw in hwList)
        {
            // new ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1);
            // Thread.Sleep(1);
            int progress = Convert.ToInt32((Double)min / hwList.Count * 100);
            min++;

            // Only report progress when it changes
            if(progress != oldProgress){
                 bgWorker.ReportProgress(progress);
                 oldProgress = progress;
            }
        }
    }

    // Updating the progress
    private void BgWorkerOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs progressChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ProgressBar.Value = progressChangedEventArgs.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now, since the progress is an integer, I report some values many times, so your code should fix the problem. Indeed the cpu cycles are being wasted. I'll try some thing with your code and if it will work, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @deefrson and Marko ... Not 100% sure, but when you update UI from a background thread, you must do it on the Dispatcher thread. Does BackgroundWorker facilitate that? Otherwise, you will be getting cross-thread exceptions.

Comment: @Darek you don't really need a Dispatcher in this case, since the BackgroundWorker is "synchronized" with the main thread. Anyway, I've read some pretty nice stuff about the amazing TPL (Task Parallel Library) coming with .NET 4.0, that facilitates many things. So this could be an alternative to BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Alternatively, you could update based on time or throttle based on `loopIndex % 10000 == 0`. (+1)

Comment: @usr i would advise against using magic numbers, if the count of the list changes the throttle number needs to adjusted/maintained. Keep it simple, report the progress only when the progress has changed no need to throttle or use time. Efficient and resilient code no need to add extra complexity.

Comment: @Marko indeed and the solution is pretty obvious, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BackgroundWorker, I developed a class named SxProgress with a very simple interface that you may use in the following way :

```
 int DesiredLinesCount = 100000 ;
 List<string> Lines=new List<string>() ;
 object[] UserObjects = new object[] { Lines } ; 
 SxProgress.Execute("Building lines",DesiredLinesCount,true,false,
                    BuildLines_ExecInThread,UserObjects)) ;

 private bool BuildLines_ExecInThread(int ItemIndex,object[] UserObjects)
{
  // some sleep to slow down the process (demonstration purpose only)
  // if (ItemIndex % 10 ==0) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) ; 
  List<string> Lines= (List<String>)UserObjects[0] ;
  Lines.Add("Hello world") ; 
  return true ; 
}
```

[The SxProgress code is in the last message of this link](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1505774/dotnet/langages/csharp/winforms-progressbar-facile-utiliser-avis/)

*Note also that the class provides the same easy interface for parallel process, creating as many threads as cores in the computer with transparent dispatch of the items to the different threads.*

Answer (score 0):

> will this work for WPF?
>   **Unfortunately no** : The class encompasses a form (winforms) with progressbar, labels and stop button.

**Possible solution** : *I never tried it.*

It may work by adding to WPF project 2 references from the "Add reference" dialog form (in ".NET" tab),i.e. "System.Windows.forms" and "WindowsFormsIntegration".

Then, in source code, add "using System.Windows.Forms;"
and   "using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;"